# Selenium Webdriver cannot locate element with correct XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, erp

I've both set implicit waits and sleeps to make sure everything has time to load, using dev tools I've painstakingly went into the element and verified the exact correct xpath > it still says unable to locate. This is the correct path, i've verified using DevTools, pasting the path in the search and it brings me right to the correct element on the webpage.

This is the XPATH > i've tried without the "//" in the front and with, i've tried going into the /span instead of the /input, it cannot locate it no matter what.

This is the code:

`

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//html/body/p21-app-root/ep-app-root/ep-shell/div/div/div[2]/p21-window/ep-view/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/p21-table-layout/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/form/div/div/div/ng-repeat/div[3]/div/div/div/div/span/input")
```

`

Also tried

```
//input[@id="tp_1_dw_1.customer_id"]
```

Picture of immediate HTML:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m40t3.png

Comment: can you post the html code of the element, that xpath is very long, its not advised to used such xpaths

Comment: Its a proprietary ERP systems HTML so most likely not. I've added a shorter selection input for the XPATH which also works in locating the correct element, it brings me right to the correct one in DevTools. But once again, the webdriver is not able to locate it - could it be its just too complex for the system to grasp?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: This is a diff from the abbove statement but the same issue > and the XPATH is verified to be the correct path as well                                                                               
                                      
                                      
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(), 'Salesrep')]"}

Comment: try to add a custom wait method before searching for the element, also print in the console "element.size()" size its basically the count of elements